# XNA Initialize in Game only called once?

Tags: c#, xna

I know that LoadContent and UnloadContent have a chance of being called more than once. However I am wondering if Initialize will have a chance to be called more than once. The documentation doesn't really go into this. Or is it better to do most of my "initialization" in the constructor?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information you are looking for is actually in the documentation for [`Game.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.run.aspx). You can only call `Game.Run` once, and it calls `Game.Initialize` once.

The benefit of doing initialization in `Initialize` instead of the constructor is that, when `Initialize` runs, the graphics device has been created (although obviously almost all of the things you can actually *do* with a graphics device should be done in `LoadContent`).

For answering this kind of question, Reflector is helpful.

Comment: Be careful, Reflector will tell you the implementation of a method, not its contract.

Comment: Just an update to my two-year-old answer: These days I recommend [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) over Reflector.